# Java - Force Instantiation on Class

Tags: java, reflection, deserialization

I keep getting the error "InstantiationException" when I try to run this code below from my custom deserializer:

```
String attr = nel.getAttribute("class");
//happens when attr = "java.awt.Color"
if (attr != null && !attr.isEmpty()){
    Object no = Class.forName(attr).newInstance(); <--- dies here
    readObject(nel, no, true);
    field.set(obj,  no);
}
```

Weird thing is that it worked at one point and now it doesn't.

How do I force the newInstance and then set the fields in that object later (which readObject does and is my own function)?

Here is some debug info:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.awt.Color
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at wms.lsw.tool.CustomXMLDecoder.readObject(CustomXMLDecoder.java:240)
at wms.lsw.tool.CustomXMLDecoder.decode(CustomXMLDecoder.java:92)
at wms.lsw.tool.Utils.openProject(Utils.java:716)
at wms.lsw.tool.SecondaryMenuBar$2.actionPerformed(SecondaryMenuBar.java:52)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:723)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:682)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:693)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

**UPDATE 1**

Ok, since the class Color needs aruguments, how I pass default stuff to a class if a class needs aruguments automatically? Or is it possible to inject a default constructor?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the full stack trace? What is the value of `attr` that leads to the exception?

Comment: The class to be instantiated either has no default constructor, or is abstract.  You cannot "force" instantiation of an class which simply can't be instantiated.

Comment: Do you control the class that you're instantiating?

Comment: @reprogrammer look at comment in the code

Comment: @ruakh I didn't make the class Color if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Scott Deutsch: It's always good to provide debug info. As you saw, this additional piece of information helped others answer your question quickly.

Comment: @reprogrammer Ok, I will add it.

Comment: Is there a way to inject a default constructor into a class? If not, how did Java build a deserializer for objects and creating them?

Comment: any one have thoughts on this matter?

Answer (score 9):

[`newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) requires a parameterless constructor, and [`Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) has no such constructor.

You need to find an appropriate [`Constructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html), and use that.

Comment: I need to find a way around that.

Answer (score 2):

**One of the reasons** should be that you try to call static method and you don't need to call `newInstance()`.

For example:

```
....
Class<?> c = Class.forName(attr);
Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String[].class };
Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", argTypes);
String[] mainArgs = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length);

main.invoke(null, (Object)mainArgs);
....
```

**Other reason**, you didn't pass arguments to constructor (verify if you have default)

for arguments use:

```
 MyClass c = MyClass .class.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("some string");
```

Comment: I need to find a way around that.